# JDBC UPDATE With preparedStatement causing java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am facing **java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).** while updating one or two columns of **'reset_info'** table which has five columns (id, mobile_tower_id, reset_value, date_time, clientip).
'id' is auto-generated primary key.
I want to **UPDATE** 'reset_value' of a particular row

Now Following is the source code:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        String sql = "UPDATE reset_info SET reset_value = ? WHERE id = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, 100);
        ps.setInt(3, 1000);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
```

And Following is my stacktrace:

```
 Connecting to database...
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
at cdot.dsa.cfms.dbconnect.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:38)
```

Is it mandatory for to put placeholder('?') for each column of the table?

Updating a single column by java.sql.Statement is working but I am getting exception with java.sql.preparedStatement.

Please help. Conceptual ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I dont see a reason for a downvote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `ps.setInt(3, 1000);` must be `ps.setInt(2, 1000);` because you only have to placeholder.

> Is it mandatory for to put placeholder('?') for each column of the table?

The placeholder is for a parameter not for a column!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have mistaken 'parameters' with 'columns'.

Answer (score 2):

you have not more than two question marks(placeholder) in your statement.
As a result of this, this must fail:

```
ps.setInt(3, 1000);
```

change it to

```
ps.setInt(2, 1000);
```